# Open media output picker programmatically

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

In Android 9 media output controls were added to the volume selection dialog.

I would like to have a button in my app which would open these system media output controls so that the user can choose where the audio will be played.

I could find nothing about this in: [Android 9 features and APIs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0), [Behavior changes: apps targeting API level 28+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28) and [Behavior changes: all apps](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all)

[image]

Comment: Were you able to find anything on this? I'm currently looking for the same answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for MediaRouter API.

```
public class MediaRouterPlaybackActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private MediaRouteSelector mSelector;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // Create a route selector for the type of routes your app supports.
      mSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
              // These are the framework-supported intents
              .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK)
              .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO)
              .build();
  }
}
```

For further reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter#java
Also check `Create a MediaRouteSelector` section.

Comment: My understanding of `MediaRouter` is that it is used to play (cast) media (video with audio) to devices like smart TVs, cars, etc. I ran both sample projects from Google and I was not able to switch between headphones or internal speaker. I even put the  `MediaRouteSelector` you wrote above and that made no difference. I want to be able to choose where my audio is played: internal microphone, wired headphones or bluetooth headphones

Answer (score 0):

I did some research about this as well so I know that Android Pie is capable of this, but they haven't provided a way for us developers to do it yet (at least I haven't found a way). The CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO in MediaRouterSelector is also only for secondary output; you can read about it on the developer website. So if you must do it, I think the only way you can do that right now is to do a workaround programmatically:

- Disconnect current device (The important of this step depends on the device; I have to do this on my Essential phone)
- Use BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices() to get a list of paired devices.
- Connect to the one you want

Answer (score -1):

Try this - it works for me on Android 11:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.settings.panel.action.MEDIA_OUTPUT");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```